# Distance between coordinates in geopandas dataframe (python)

Tags: python, lambda, distance, geopandas, euclidean-distance

[image]

I am trying to find the distance between start and end coordinates in the new column

I tried

```
distance.distance((gdf_final['start_lat'][0],gdf_final['start_lng'][0]), 
                  (gdf_final['end_lat'][0],gdf_final['end_lng'][0])).meters
```

and gave me the correct answer, but when I tried

```
gdf['distance'] = gdf.apply(lambda x: distance.distance(((x['start_lat'],x['start_lng']), 
                                                         (x['end_lat'],x['end_lng']))), axis=1)

gdf_final
```

To apply this function to create a whole new column with the distance, but I am keep getting

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: What is `distance.distance()` function? What args and their types it requires?

Comment: stack overflow asks that we not upload pictures of data/text/code/logs/etc when asking questions for [a variety of reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/). can you edit your question and just paste the result of `print(df)` rather than taking a screenshot? thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `the correct answer` is obtained from Euclidean distance using geographic coordinates (lat,long) in degrees?